# erro na comparaçao de binários em C

Tags: c, socket, perl

Tenho um programa em Perl que conecta num socket, recebe binários neste socket, lê os binarios recebidos, compara com outros binários em um buffer para eu saber se existem esses binários no buffer recebido no socket. Vejam:

**perlProgram.pl**

```
# some code here ...

my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr => $host, PeerPort => 666, Proto => 'tcp');   

$sock->sockopt(SO_LINGER, pack("ii", 1, 0));


# some code here for another porposes...
# ...


read($sock, $buff, 0xfffff);

close($sock);

if (($v = index $buff, "\xC7\x44\x24\x08\x03\x00\x00\x00\xC7\x04\x24\x00\x00\x00\x00\x89\x44\x24\x04") >= 0) {
    $offset = $v;

    printf "your offset is %08x\n", $offset;
} else {
    if (($v = index $buff, "\x89\x44\x24\x10\xA1\xBC\xA5\x0F\x08\x89\x44\x24\x04\xe8") >= 0) {
        $offset = $v;

    printf "your offset is %08x\n", $offset;
    } else {
        print "Could not find your binaries\n";
        exit;
    }
}


# more code here ...
```

Este programa em Perl roda perfeitamente, e eu tenho certeza que os binarios estao vindo no socket, e que os binarios que eu quero estao no buffer. Então eu escrevi o mesmo programa em C, e eis que surge o problema: em C eu não consigo verificar se os binários no buffer do socket existem mesmo, pois eu tenho certeza que eles estão vindo mas não consigo verificar programaticamente. Vejam:

**sameProgramInC.c:**

```
// some code here ...

char binaries_1[]="\xc7\x44\x24\x08\x03\x00\x00\x00\xc7\x04\x24\x00\x00\x00\x00\x89\x44\x24\x04";
char binaries_2[]="\x89\x44\x24\x10\xa1\xbc\xa5\x0f\x08\x89\x44\x24\x04\xe8";

int indexOf(const unsigned char *data_buffer, const unsigned int length, const unsigned char *needle, const unsigned int needlelen) {
   unsigned int i, j, index=0;
   for(i=0; i < length-needlelen; i++) {
      if(data_buffer[i] == needle[0]){
         index=i;
         for(j=1; j < needlelen; j++){
            if(data_buffer[i+j] != needle[j]){
               index=0;
               break;
            }
         }
         if(index == i){
            return index;
         }
      }
   }
   return index;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int sockfd, buflen;
   struct hostent *host_info;
   struct sockaddr_in target_addr;
   unsigned char read_buffer[0xfffff];

   if((host_info = gethostbyname(argv[1])) == NULL)
      fatal("looking up hostname");

   if ((sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
      fatal("in socket");

   target_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   target_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);   
   target_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)host_info->h_addr);
   memset(&(target_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8); // zero the rest of the struct

   if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&target_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
      fatal("connecting to target server");

   // some code here for another porposes...
   // ...

   printf("\n\t Attempting to read memory of the server...");
   bzero(read_buffer, sizeof(read_buffer));
   read(sockfd, read_buffer, 0xfffff);

   index = indexOf(read_buffer, sizeof(read_buffer), binaries_1, sizeof(binaries_1));    
   if(index != 0){
      printf("\n\t [+] your offset is 0x%08x", index);
   } else {
      index = indexOf(read_buffer, sizeof(read_buffer), binaries_2, sizeof(binaries_2));      
      if(index != 0){
         printf("\n\t [+] your offset is 0x%08x", index);
      } else {
         printf("\n\t [-] Fail! Could not find your offset!");
      }
   }

   // more code here
```

Então, este código em C não roda como meu código em Perl. Não há erros de executo, somente meu codigo em C nao consegue verificar se os binários estao no buffer como o codigo em Perl consegue. Eu tentei usar `memmem()`, `memcmp()` e `strstr()`, mas também nao funcionam. Porque isso ocorre? O que está errado? Há algo de errado com meu `indexOf()`?

Eu fiz a mesma pergunta no stackoverflow internacional, se quiserem responder lá, fiquem à vontade: [errors in binary comparation in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466012/errors-in-binary-comparation-in-c)

Comment: Pegue a resposta que você obteve lá no SO e poste aqui pra deixar com uma resposta válida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando é especificado `sizeof(binaries_1)` como comprimento da substring de binarios a ser pesquisados no buffer, inclui o zero à direita (terminador de string). Entao é só mudar para `sizeof(binaries_1)-1` que o problema é resolvido. Um classico off-by-one erro.

Creditos: Anton Savin do stackoverflow.com